# Info about pixel size and DPI for file

Tags: adobe-photoshop, dpi, pixel

I'm working with an artist who is sending me png files. According to the printer, these files are to be 825 px x 1125 px at 300dpi. Seems straightforward enough to me. However, the artist keeps sending me files at 1650 px x 2250 px at 72 dpi though I've reiterated what size I need.

Here's the question. Is there a technical reason why, as an experienced artist, he's doing this? Does he know something I don't about pixels and dpi (like maybe this is a non-issue)? Or is he just being a jerk, lazy, or not paying attention? I'm still a novice at graphic design so I want to know if there's a good technical reason why he might be doing this before I make an issue out of it. Thanks.

Comment: PNGs are a terrible format for printing as many Raster Image Processing solutions don't support them. Even without the DPI issue he should be sending stuff through as a TIFF or JPG in a CMYK colour mode

Comment: @Jackson Hyde, the responsable of converting a file to CMYK is for the designer. As an digital artis it is totally fine sending an RGB image and PNG is a well accepted format for this case.

Comment: That's what I'm saying - the designer should be sending through CMYK images.

Also, if you're working with a decent printer and you send them PNGs, they will laugh at you behind your back. And they would be right.

Comment: @JacksonHyde the *designer* should send the printer CMYK print ready files yes, but an *artist* sending a designer RGB raster artwork is pretty normal.

Comment: The artist should know that RGB is not the colour mode to use for printed material. Not to mention the difference between a designer and an artist is purely semantic.

Comment: Maybe, I'm just saying it's normal. But an artist and a designer are definitely not the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a pixel size requirement, DPI (PPI) is mostly meaningless; All that matters is the size in pixels. The PPI would only matter if you were giving the artist a *physical* size requirement. See [my answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/82907/52050) to [I need some help understanding DPI](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/82903/52050).

That being said, all your artist is doing is sending you his artwork at x2 scale; it's common to work at a higher resolution than needed and shouldn't cause you any issues. Just be thankful he isn't sending it at half size.

Comment: Actually Guy could be thankfull he is sending a 2x file so he has an original file in case you need it. He also could charge more for a 2x file if it was not asked originally. n_n

Comment: Charing a client based on the pixel size of the deliverable is one of the most ridiculous things I've ever heard.

Comment: @JacksonHyde it's not ridiculous at all... for example, you pay more for larger stock images don't you?

Comment: Licensed assets should be itemised separately. In most cases the size of the deliverable should not change how much work is required.