# How do a resize an existing poster I made in Inkscape easily?

Tags: inkscape

I made a 24" x 36" poster in Inkscape; the design contains a few layers. I exported it to a PNG file with 300 DPI so that I could get the poster made by a vendor.

I am interested in making the same poster but it is larger (32" x 48"). Note that the aspect ratio remains the same.

How do I do that easily in Inkscape? I understand that I could just output using a higher (scaled-up) PPI. Thank you.

Comment: Upscale the original document in Inkscape native format. Then export a .png again at the larger size.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/107888/check-dpi-of-png-file

Comment: @Kyle Would you please elaborate on how I can upscale the original document in the Inkscape native format? Do I scale up every object in every layer? Thanks.

Comment: I am an Illustrator user but I have Inkscape- I opened it and in the Transform panel select the Scale tab and Scale everything by 125% including your Artboard (or what ever Inkscape calls it). There are many here who are very good with Inkscape and will possibly give you a step by step.

Comment: No. Do not scale anything. I m adding my answer to solve it just exporting it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

A print of 200PPI is in most cases a very good resolution. If you use the same file you will get a print of 225PPI, which is a good print resolution.

But if you want to keep the same 300PPI to "play safe" we need to do some math.

48/36 = 1.333

So we need to export at a new resolution:

**300x1.333 = 400PPI**

This screen capture is in Spanish but simply change that number

[image]

You will notice that the final pixel width will change from 7200 to 9600 and the height from 10800 to 14400. Now you have the extra pixels needed.

**Just remember to say to your provider that you want a print of 32x48 using 300PPI, not a 24x36 print at 400PPI.**

Comment: Thanks. Good answer. That's what I did last night, by outputting to a PNG at 400 PPI.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to enlarge without messing around with converting to bitmap, it can be done easily.

1. Enable Snapping, and Snapping to Nodes, Snapping to Cusp Nodes, and Snapping to page borders

[image]

2. Draw a rectangle over your design to fit the page exactly. The snapping will make this easy.
3. Select All, then Group
4. Switch to the Select Object tool if not already selected, and make sure the group is selected.
5. In the Tools Control bar, enter the new width and height.
6. Do *Edit > Resize Page to Selection*. This will set the page size to the resized content.
7. Ungroup, and delete the rectangle you drew.

That's it!